# Getting Data from ContactsContract.Contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I have an Address Book in an emulator with one entity in it.

I create a contact chooser for my contacts:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setData(ContactsContract.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_CODE);
```

I select the single entry in my address book and I get back an intent that has a data uri like:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0n354B31353539292D4553313F3F39/1/
```

Cool it's a CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI for ContactsContract.Contacts. I can use it immediately to get things directly accessible in ContactsContract.Contacts, like the display name. Awesome great. Ok now let's say I want to get data from ContactsContract.Contacts.Data or ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo for that user. Reading the documentation for both CONTENT_DIRECTORY entries in both ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo/Data:

```
This directory can be used either with a CONTENT_URI or CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI.
```

So I tried what's logical:

```
uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
Cursor c = myContentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null); // simplified
...
```

Now I get an error that is annoying:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0n354B31353539292D4553313F3F39/1/photo
```

What the heck? 
The Contact has a display name, and yes it has a photo. Why is this considered incorrect? I have tried this on both 2.1 and 2.2 so far.

[Documentation for ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html)

Comment: I have a strong assumption that this documentation was updated referencing the behavior of the lastest version of the OS and that this behavior is not compatible with previous versions supporting the same API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is late but I hope somebody can find it helpful.

For android < 3.0 it doesn't work. Use instead the _ID:

```
Uri contactUri;
//if at least HC uses lookupUri which is more efficient; for previous versions does not work
if (AT_LEAST_HONEYCOMB) {
    contactUri = getLookupUri(contactId, contactLookupKey);
} else {
    contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, "" + contactId);
}
Uri contactDetailsUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

// contactDetailsUri android<3.0: com.android.contacts/contacts/1/data 
//contactDetailsUri android>=3.0: com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0n354B31353539292D4553313F3F39/1/data



Cursor detailsCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    contactDetailsUri,
                    PROJECTION,
                    null,
                    null,
                    SORT_ORDER);
```

PS: sorry for ugly code

Comment: Yep I believe that's what I ended up doing in the end.

Comment: is this uri used to register contentObserver for single contact ? contactUri = getLookupUri(contactId, contactLookupKey);

Comment: How to get the contactLookupKey ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get **PhoneNumber** of a Contact from `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`

```
    String contactID = null;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
            null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        contactID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    }

    cursor.close();

    // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
    Cursor cursorPhone = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

            new String[]{contactID},
            null);

    if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
        phoneNo = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }

    cursorPhone.close();
```